# How to convert the dynamic date to particular format

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I tried to convert string date to a specific format, 
(i.e)
1995-09-22 to 22 Sep 1995

```
let dat = new Date();
      var options = { day: "numeric", month: "long", year: "numeric" };
      let local = dat.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
      console.log(local);


// With dynamic date string(Not working)
let dat = "1995-09-22"
      var options = { day: "numeric", month: "long", year: "numeric" };
      let local = dat.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
      console.log(local); // 22 Sep 1995
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DatePipe` for that

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ksfe9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){
       console.log(this.datePipe.transform("1995-09-22", 'dd MMM yyyy'))
    }
}
```

Comment: @trichetriche please check stackblitz demo

Comment: My bad, didn't see the provider in the decorator !

Comment: Yes I have also used DatePipe for converting date format. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this :

```
  let dat = new Date("1995-09-22");
  var options = { day: "numeric", month: "long", year: "numeric" };
  let local = dat.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  console.log(local); // 22 Sep 1995
```

FYI : not tested code